# What may I benefit from switching my development platform to VIM, what may I lose?

Tags: eclipse, vim, ubuntu, ide, qt-creator

When I first learned to program I learned to do so with an IDE, and that has stuck with me until recently. The last few months I have been using gedit for a web based project and while the project turned out quite well ([check it out here](http://peizo.selfip.org/signage)), I felt like gedit didn't provide anything extraordinarily useful. As of now, my two favourite IDE's are Eclipse and Qt Creator. On my laptop (a Zenbook running Ubuntu) Qt Creator starts in one second and Eclipse starts in five, so performance is not an issue. So what would I lose from switching to VIM and what could I gain?

Comment: This question has been asked/answered so many times. You need to google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not about how fast it starts, although it does indeed start faster. It's about how fast you can edit. By never taking your hands off the keyboard you gain huge amounts of speed and priceless inner peace. You also step into the wonderful world of command line bliss. Things are literally black and white (well, if you wanted them to be). It makes life simple... efficient... fun. Once you go mouseless you never go back.